# What's wrong with my code that this error occurs?

Tags: flutter, dart

> Error: type'_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast

I just want to show the data on the screen, very simple, but it is not working in any way. the API is returning me the necessary data correctly because show me on the console but do not know how to call in View.

My Model:

```
class ProdutosModel {
  int codigo;
  String codigoBarras;
  String descricao;
  double preco;

  ProdutosModel({
    this.codigo,
    this.codigoBarras,
    this.descricao,
    this.preco,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'codigo': codigo,
      'codigoBarras': codigoBarras,
      'descricao': descricao,
      'preco': preco,
    };
  }

  factory ProdutosModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return ProdutosModel(
      codigo: map['codigo'],
      codigoBarras: map['codigoBarras'],
      descricao: map['descricao'],
      preco: map['preco'],
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory ProdutosModel.fromJson(String source) =>
      ProdutosModel.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```

My controller:

```
Future getterProducts() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final token = prefs.getString('token');

    try {
      final response = await Dio().get(
        'CONFIDENTIAL#CONFIDENTIAL#CONFIDENTIAL#',
        options: Options(
          headers: {'Token': token},
        ),
      );

      print(response.data);

      if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
        var getProducts = response.data as List;
        var listProducts =
            getProducts.map((i) => ProdutosModel.fromJson(i)).toList();
        return listProducts;
      }
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

And my view:

```
class HomeView extends GetView<HomeController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(150.0),
        child: AppBar(
          elevation: 10,
          flexibleSpace: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [
                  Color(0xff38EF7D),
                  Color(0xff11998E),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          title: Text(''),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: controller.listProducts,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  
                  var prod = (snapshot.data as List<ProdutosModel>)[index];
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text('${prod.descricao}'),
                  );
                },
                /* itemCount: (snapshot.data as List<ProdutosModel>).length */);
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('${snapshot.error}'));
          }
          return Center(
            child:
                CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.cyanAccent),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          //
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.refresh,
          color: Colors.green[700],
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Let me know error line or source.

Comment: The error message is clear, you are trying to cast a Map type as List type, this error should be located in the response from your HTTP request.

Comment: That's where the problem is, it doesn't show me any errors in the console but in "snapshot.hasError" :/

Answer (score 0):

Change fromJson to fromMap in MyController

```
var listProducts =
            getProducts.map((i) => ProdutosModel.fromMap(i)).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if **response.data** is indeed a list that you are receiving from the Api, and not a json object with a list inside. If not a list, then

var getProducts = response.data as List;

This type cast wont work and will throw an error.

You can go to https://app.quicktype.io/ and just copy paste the entire response. Choose dart as the language and you'll get the proper serialization.

Let me know if that helped. Otherwise provide the Api json response here.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs from this line:

`var getProducts = response.data as List;`

This is because the API is returning a `Map` instead of a list, hence the error

> type'_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast

Try accessing the data through the correct property of `response.data`, for example `response.data['data']`

**Quick note:** In your UI code block, it'd be better to define the type like this for the type-check to work at the bloc level:

```
//... other lines

// Define the type of data here
FutureBuilder<List<ProdutosModel>>(

        // Since I'm getting this method from your code, I'm using it here
        future: controller.getterProducts(), 

        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  
                  // We can use `snapshot.data` right away without type-cast here
                  var prod = snapshot.data[index];
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text('${prod.descricao}'),
                  );
                },
                /* itemCount: (snapshot.data as List<ProdutosModel>).length */);
          }

//... other lines
```